# replacing data from one table with data from another model

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I want is to combine my Categories and Translations tables while creating a data request from the database. or just to write the TextContentIDForName value with the Translation value in my Categories table.

I never want to make any changes in my database. I just want to have it show me the translation texts when I want to write my categories on my page. I designed my database schema in this way, as I knew that the translated texts should be kept in a separate table.

First of all I can't find any property that joins these two tables or looks like this property.

In short, I have a table for my categories and a translation table holding each language. Apart from these two tables, I have a TextContent table that I created to give IDs to the posts.

### My query to pull all categories looks like this.

```
public void getAllCategories() {
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference categoriesRef = db.getReference("categories");
    DatabaseReference TranslationsRef = db.getReference("translations");

    ArrayList<Categories> categoriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Query query = categoriesRef.orderByChild("parentID").equalTo("categories");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            categoriesArrayList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Categories categories = data.getValue(Categories.class);
                assert categories != null;

                categories.setKey(data.getKey());
                categoriesArrayList.add(categories);
            }
            categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

### If I want to add translation texts to my query of all categories.

Creating two queries for the two tables and copying them into a common model would have helped me see all the information, but it's not very flexible. I need to create an extra model to join two tables.

```java
public void getAllCategories() {
        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference categoriesRef = db.getReference("categories");
        DatabaseReference TranslationsRef = db.getReference("translations");

        Query query = categoriesRef.orderByChild("parentID").equalTo("categories");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                categoriesArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    CategoriesAndTranslations categoriesAndTranslations = data
                            .getValue(CategoriesAndTranslations.class);
                    assert categoriesAndTranslations != null;

                    categoriesAndTranslations.setKey(data.getKey());

                    categoriesArrayList.add(categoriesAndTranslations);
                    System.out.println("1234" + categoriesAndTranslations);

                    String textContentID = categoriesAndTranslations.getTextContentID();

                    Query query = TranslationsRef.orderByChild("textContentID")
                            .equalTo(textContentID);
                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                                CategoriesAndTranslations categoriesAndTranslations = data
                                        .getValue(CategoriesAndTranslations.class);
                                System.out.println("123" + categoriesAndTranslations);
                                categoriesArrayList.add(categoriesAndTranslations);

                            }
                            categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                    categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

All data modeled by this method **will have a null value.** I do not know why it happened.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want my Translations and Categories table to be combined with my model after being queried one by one.
Since you made this comment, I decided to add the methods I've tried and failed before to this question.

To add to my question, I noticed it working while rewriting the code I tried yesterday. I've added this code as an answer below.

Comment: Is there a document that I can reference so that the use of Firebase Realtime Database can be more efficient, @AlexMamo?

Comment: What exactly is not efficient in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As it is difficult to use a common pattern, after fetching my entire Categories table, I tried to replace the textContentIDForName with the translation in my Translations table.

```java
public void getAllCategories() {
        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference categoriesRef = db.getReference("categories");
        DatabaseReference TranslationsRef = db.getReference("translations");

        Query query = categoriesRef.orderByChild("parentID").equalTo("categories");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                categoriesArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Categories categories = data
                            .getValue(Categories.class);
                    assert categories != null;

                    categories.setKey(data.getKey());

                    categoriesArrayList.add(categories);
                    System.out.println("1234" + categories);

                    String textContentID = categories.getTextContentIDForName();

                    Query query = TranslationsRef.orderByChild("textContentID")
                            .equalTo(textContentID);
                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                                Translations translations = data.getValue(Translations.class);

                                System.out.println("123" + translations);
                                categories.setTextContentIDForName(translations.getTranslation());

                            }
                            categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**This method is a solution** and it works well.

[image]

Now the textContentIDForName value has been replaced with the Translation value from Translations. This way i was able to fetch the translation text.